# Como deixar duas telas em uma activity, podendo trocar uma delas via codigo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

Bom dia, tarde ou noite !!
Preciso fazer uma tela no android divida no meio, onde a tela em cima tela um player de video, e a parte de baixo um chat, onde em um devido evento será substituída por outra tela, uma tela de chamada que ao aceitar seria mais uma vez substituída por outra, sem mudar a tela superior (o player de video).

---

```
Tela um
```

---

```
  tela 2
```

---

A tela 1 sempre ficará, e a tela 2 poderá ser substituída por outra tela,
tentei por fragment mas infelizmente deu erro, então se alguém poder me dar uma luz eu fico agradecido, Obrigado

[EDIT1]
   o codigo do xml que tentei e deu erro

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
>


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="fragmentAovivo.videoFragem"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_video_fragem"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    >
</fragment>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/borda_chamada"
    />
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container2"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"


    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_chat">



</fragment>
```

---

o ERRO.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.byb.tvcel/com.byb.tvcel.AoVivoScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
        at com.byb.tvcel.AoVivoScreen.onCreate(AoVivoScreen.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class fragmentAovivo.videoFragem that is not a Fragment
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895) 
        at com.byb.tvcel.AoVivoScreen.onCreate(AoVivoScreen.java:14) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584) 
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560) 
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895) 
        at com.byb.tvcel.AoVivoScreen.onCreate(AoVivoScreen.java:14) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Poste o que você tem até agora

Comment: Postado o código xml da activity que tentei !

Comment: Jean, porque não usar apenas 1 fragmento? Se a tela 1 não muda de lugar, faça dela uma hierarquia de views e abaixo disso, coloque o container do fragmento.

Comment: @LennoardSilva poderia fazer isso, porem tem uma possibilidade de ter que mudar ela também, então teria que ser as duas, obrigado pela resposta.